# Using AJAX to retrieve data from JSON File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

so I am trying to read the data from my JSON file and display it on the webpage using HTML. It would work with simple keys with this particular database it wouldn't work for me.

JSON:

```
var carInfo = [
{
    carId: 1,
    carPrice : 15.00,
},
{
    carId: 2,
    carPrice : 25.00,
}
];
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("vehicle_data.json", function(data) {

        $.each(data.carInfo, function() {

            $("ul").append("<li>Car ID: "+this[carInfo[0].carId]);

        });         
    });     
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<ul></ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="json_data_retrieve.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a valid JSON file. It is a JS script.

```
var carInfo = [
    {
        carId: 1,
        carPrice : 15.00,
    },
    {
        carId: 2,
        carPrice : 25.00,
    }
];
```

Try this:

```
{
    "carInfo": 
    [
        {
            "carId": 1,
            "carPrice": 15
        },
        {
            "carId": 2,
            "carPrice": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update:**
You may load this script as a script source in an HTML. It must be an .js file.

```
<script src="vehicle_data.js"></script>
```

If you need to load it dynamically, use jQuery `$.getScript` method.
It doesn't matter that it has .json extensions because it will be evaluated as a script.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.getScript("vehicle_data.json", function() 
    {
        // Pay attention. In this case, you work with carInfo 
        // variable because it has been executed as a script, 
        // but not loaded as a JSON file.
        $.each(carInfo, function()             {
            $("ul").append("<li>Car ID: " + this[carInfo[0].carId]);
        });         
    });     
});
```

However, it is **very** strange that someone gives you .json file with JS declaration and tells you that you should execute it but shouldn't rename it or load as a script.

Comment: Is there a way to parse that JSON file as JS file? Only asking since I have only provided a small sample of the database. Changing all the fields would be very time consuming.

Comment: @user3645858 Since you have a proper JS file, you can just add it to your page as a script. `<script src="vehicle_data.js"></script>`. If you add it before your `json_data_retrieve.js`, then you can refer to it's objects in this script.

Comment: So will I need to change the file extension and then add the new script source? If so, I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: @user3645858 Such a strange condition. Take a look at the update of answer, please.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time. Now it is finally reading the file but all the carId values are showing up as undefined.

Comment: Never mind. Got it working. Just had to remove the this keyword since we are reading the script directly.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you are trying to iterate the parent object from within itself.
Try this

```
$.each(data.carInfo, function(k, v) {

        $("ul").append("<li>Car ID: "+v.carId);

    });
```